# How to change links in the 3 main categories, on widget category, to a javascript function call

Tags: php, categories, widgets, jquery

I'd like to know..

How could I change my 3 main categories links, so they call a javascript function?

I'm using Snapshot Theme from WooThemes.

Here's the current state of the website:

http://www.mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/

The categories I'd like to change the links to a javascript function call, are: ***Masculino***, ***Feminino*** and ***Infantil***.

They are at a container with class `widget`.

EDIT:

I´ve changed the jquery.

I've tried to use jquery in `index.php`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".widget ul li > a").not("ul li ul li>a").attr("href", "javascript:hideMenu();showSubMenu('m-submenu');");
$(".widget ul li+li > a").not("ul li+li ul li>a").attr("href", "javascript:hideMenu();showSubMenu('f-submenu');");
$(".widget ul li+li+li > a").not("ul li+li+li ul li>a").attr("href", "javascript:hideMenu();showSubMenu('i-submenu');");

});
```

But, it seems that some sub-categories are calling the javascript function.
In other words, my .not() it´s not working in some cases.

What could I do?

Thanks.

Comment: The Answer is:
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".widget ul li > a:not(ul li ul li>a, ul li+li ul li>a,ul li+li+li ul li>a     
    )").attr("href", "javascript:hideMenu();showSubMenu('m-submenu')");
 $(".widget ul li+li > a:not(ul li ul li>a, ul li+li ul li>a,ul li+li+li ul li>a 
    )").attr("href", "javascript:hideMenu();showSubMenu('f-submenu');");
 $(".widget ul li+li+li > a:not(ul li ul li>a, ul li+li ul li>a,ul li+li+li ul li>a 
    )").attr("href", "javascript:hideMenu();showSubMenu('i-submenu');");
    });
I must use `:not` to discard any possible match for every main category.

Comment: So you found the answer? Next time you should use StackOverflow.com to find jQuery answers. You are using wordpress, but you're problem is jQuery. Have a nice day Brazuca.

Comment: I´m not sure.

Maybe there´s a wordpress core code better answer.
Editing a category.php, category-template.php, or something.

That would make life easier.

I will have to add the jquery and javascript functions to each page.

Comment: If you've got your answer, be sure to post and mark as answered.

Comment: Have to wait some hours until there

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#f-submenu").hide();
$("#m-submenu").hide();
$("#i-submenu").hide();
$(".widget ul li > a:not(ul li ul li>a, ul li+li ul li>a,ul li+li+li ul li>a     
)").attr("href", "javascript:hideMenu();showSubMenu('m-submenu')");
$(".widget ul li+li > a:not(ul li ul li>a, ul li+li ul li>a,ul li+li+li ul li>a 
)").attr("href", "javascript:hideMenu();showSubMenu('f-submenu');");
$(".widget ul li+li+li > a:not(ul li ul li>a, ul li+li ul li>a,ul li+li+li ul li>a 
)").attr("href", "javascript:hideMenu();showSubMenu('i-submenu');");
});
```

It seems I must enter every possible undesirable match in each `:not`